# error 13 errorbar excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

The problem with the error bars seems to be resolved, but now I am gettng a error 5. The error line is:

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels AutoText:=False, LegendKey:=False, ShowSeriesName:=False, ShowCategoryName:=False, ShowValue:=True, _
        ShowPercentage:=False, ShowBubbleSize:=False

```
 'resize chart
WS.ChartObjects(1).Width = 500
WS.ChartObjects(1).Height = chartmultipl * (rowcnt - 1 - minscale)
WS.ChartObjects(1).Left = chartleftpos
WS.ChartObjects(1).Top = 70
'Rescale values to positions in chart so that labels can be succesfully moved
minchar = ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale
maxchar = ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale
midchar = (maxchar + minchar) / 2
'datalabels
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels AutoText:=False, LegendKey:=False, ShowSeriesName:=False, ShowCategoryName:=False, ShowValue:=True, _
    ShowPercentage:=False, ShowBubbleSize:=False
For i = 1 To rowcnt - 1
    If WS.Cells(i + 1, labelcol) <> "" Then
        With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).DataLabel
            .Characters.Text = Left(WS.Cells(i + 1, labelcol).Value, 28)
            .AutoScaleFont = False
            With .Characters(Start:=1, Length:=100).Font
                .Name = "Arial"
                If WS.Cells(i + 1, labelcol).Font.Italic = True Then
                    .FontStyle = "Italic"
                ElseIf WS.Cells(i + 1, labelcol).Font.Bold = True Or Not ptype Then
                    .FontStyle = "Bold"
                Else
                    .FontStyle = "Normal"
                End If
                .Size = labelsize
                .Strikethrough = False
                .Superscript = False
                .Subscript = False
                .OutlineFont = False
                .Shadow = False
                .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
                .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            End With
            'move labels wherever there is enough space to display them or to the beginning of the graph
            If ptype Then
                textsize = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Len(WS.Cells(i + 1, labelcol).Value), 28)
                If WS.Cells(i + 1, int1).Value <= midchar Then
                    .Left = 15 + Round(ActiveChart.PlotArea.Width * (WS.Cells(i + 1, 6).Value - minchar) / (maxchar - minchar))
                Else
                    .Left = -textsize * 3 + Round(ActiveChart.PlotArea.Width * (WS.Cells(i + 1, 5).Value - minchar) / (maxchar - minchar))
                End If
            Else
                .Left = 20
            End If
        End With
    End If
Next i
'if it's an outcome graph use set square sizes, if a final MA graph use study weights
If Not ptype Then
    For i = 1 To resultcount
        With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i)
            .MarkerSize = Round(sqsize(i), 0)
        End With
    Next i
End If
'send chart to back for future merging
WS.ChartObjects(1).SendToBack
'ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
'Selection.ShapeRange.ZOrder msoSendToBack
'deselect graph so that I can add the rest of the shapes but first save things that are needed
minsc = ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale
maxsc = ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale
WS.Range("A1").Select
'if it is the final scatterplot add the diamonds
If Not ptype Then
    Dim plarealeft, plarearight As Double
    Dim dheight, incrh As Double
    Dim origleft, origlength, transleft As Double
    Dim diampos, diamlength As Double
    Dim grtop As Double
    'left and right edge of plot area in pixels
    plarealeft = 371
    plarearight = 827
    'diamond statistics
    dheight = 10
    'vertical alignment of diamonds - increment from one to another
    incrh = WS.ChartObjects(1).Height / ((rowcnt - 1) - minscale + 2)
    'top of the graph
    grtop = WS.ChartObjects(1).Top
    'get all info in tables so that I can use in loops
    mu(1) = fe_mu
    mu(2) = dl_mu
    mu(3) = ml_mu
    mu(4) = pl_mu
    mu(5) = T_mu
    mvar(1) = fe_var
    mvar(2) = dl_var
    mvar(3) = ml_var
    mvar(4) = pl_var
    mvar(5) = T_var
    For i = 1 To 4
        tmargin(i) = 1.96
    Next i
    tmargin(5) = Excel.WorksheetFunction.TInv(0.05, resultcount - 1)
    tlabel(1) = "FE"
    tlabel(2) = "DL"
    tlabel(3) = "ML"
    tlabel(4) = "PL"
    tlabel(5) = "T"
    'go through all 5 diamonds
    For i = 1 To 5
        'original length and far left position
        origleft = mu(i) - tmargin(i) * (mvar(i) ^ (1 / 2))
        origlength = 2 * tmargin(i) * (mvar(i) ^ (1 / 2))
        'transform to [0,1] scale
        transleft = (origleft - minsc) / (maxsc - minsc)
        'transform to points
        diampos = plarealeft + (plarearight - plarealeft) * transleft + 1
        diamlength = (plarearight - plarealeft) * origlength / (maxsc - minsc)
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeDiamond, diampos, grtop + (rowcnt - 1.5 + i + 1) * incrh - dheight / 2, diamlength, dheight).Select
        Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, diampos + diamlength + 10, grtop + (rowcnt - 1.5 + i + 1) * incrh - dheight / 2, 20, 12).Select
        Selection.Characters.Text = tlabel(i)
        With Selection.ShapeRange
            .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
            .Line.Visible = msoFalse
        End With
        With Selection.Font
            .Name = "Arial"
            .FontStyle = "Bold"
            .Size = 9
        End With
    Next i
End If
'add text files with study information
If ptype Then
    tboxend = rowcnt * 10
    tboxstep = (tboxend - 80) / (rowcnt - 2)
    For i = 2 To rowcnt
        If (WS.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" And WS.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value = "") Or i = 2 Then
            'find how many outcomes there are in each study to better align the text boxes
            j = i
            Do
                j = j + 1
            Loop Until WS.Cells(j, 1).Value = ""
            cntr = j - i
            'create textbox
            tboxpos = tboxend - (i - 2) * tboxstep - (cntr - 1) * tboxstep / 2
            ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 500, tboxpos, 60, 25).Select
            Selection.Characters.Text = WS.Cells(i, 1).Value
            With Selection.ShapeRange
                .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
                .Line.Visible = msoFalse
            End With
            With Selection.Font
                .Name = "Arial"
                .FontStyle = "Bold"
                .Size = 10
                .Strikethrough = False
                .Superscript = False
                .Subscript = False
                .OutlineFont = False
                .Shadow = False
                .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
                .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            End With
        End If
    Next i
End If
'create a list with all the shapes that need to be selected and group them
j = 0
For Each Sh In WS.Shapes
    If Not Left(Sh.Name, 7) = "Comment" Then
        j = j + 1
        ReDim Preserve sharray(j)
        sharray(j) = Sh.Name
    End If
Next Sh
WS.Shapes.Range(sharray).Group
'deselect shape
WS.Range("A1").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: Sorry, can you just tell us the line that causes the error, instead of making us carefully comb through 50 lines of code for it?

Comment: Yes, the error line is marked with *

Comment: ErrorBar Direction:=xlX, Include:=xlBoth, Type:=xlCustom, Amount:=edata, MinusValues:=edata

Comment: To fix the formatting you need to indent every line 4 spaces. Select all the code in your VBA editor and tab it in then copy and paste it back here.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do, to help track down the error is to define all your variables properly.

Example: your first line

```
Dim rowcnt, textsize, cntr, labeltop As Integer
```

is actually the same as this:

```
Dim rowcnt as Variant  
Dim textsize as Variant  
dim cntr as Variant  
dim labeltop As Integer
```

doing this may bring up other errors that can help you track down what is causing the line to fail

Comment: Thank you,I modified the coding following your suggestions, but still got the error on the same line.

Comment: Ha! Got it! Thank you :-) But now I get Error 5 "Invalid procedude call or argument" Here is the code again, the error line is at the end, marked with ***

Comment: ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels AutoText:=False, LegendKey:=False, ShowSeriesName:=False, ShowCategoryName:=False, ShowValue:=True, _
        ShowPercentage:=False, ShowBubbleSize:=False

Answer (score 0):

Declare `Option Explicit` at the top of your code, it will help you write better code by forcing you to declare all variables and help you identify bugs more easily.

This is probably causing your Invalid Call or Argument error:

```
'get the last row of data
rowcnt = LASTINCOLUMN2(6, k)
```

Unless you have a custom function called `LASTINCOLUMN2` that you didn't post?

To get the last row use:

```
rowcnt = WS.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Declare rowcnt as `Long` not an `integer`.

You need to define:
`ptype`
`resultcount`
`vareffects`

**Edit:** I am still running through your code and identifying many unidentified  subs/functions. Is there a second part to the code?

Comment: Function LASTINCOLUMN2(ByVal clmn As Long, ByVal k As Integer) As Long
    Dim WorkRange As Range
    Dim CellCount, i As Long
    Application.Volatile
    Set WorkRange = Worksheets(k).Columns(clmn).EntireColumn
    Set WorkRange = Intersect(WorkRange.Parent.UsedRange, WorkRange)
    CellCount = WorkRange.Count
    For i = CellCount To 1 Step -1
        If Not IsEmpty(WorkRange(i)) Then
            LASTINCOLUMN2 = WorkRange(i).Row
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function

Comment: Post additional code in the original question so it's easy to read :)

Comment: Does this help? The code is for a meta-analysis, so there is a lot before creating the chart. Let me know if you want the entire thisn or if there are specific variables you would like me to post. thanks again

Comment: Yes please. Edit your original post and add in the full code including functions that are called in your main sub.

Comment: The code is as long as the day, is there a more specific variable you would like me to post?

Comment: Please declare `Option Explicit` and step through the code to make sure all your variables are declared. This might help us narrow it down.

Comment: After running through with Option Explicit, there is an error on this line:    Private Sub rev_effects(ByVal k As Integer)